# How to upload files from subdomain folder to root folder in laravel?

Tags: laravel

I have a subdomain folder as abc.xyz.com inside public_html folder that has a laravel project. Now I am uploading image from subdomain folder. But I want to store the images in the main domain i.e xyz.com that has a laravel project. How can I do that? Please help
This is the image upload I am using:

```
<?php

if ($request->hasFile('frontimage')) {

    $file_frontimage = $request->file('frontimage');
    $actual_filename_frontimage = $file_frontimage->getClientOriginalName();
    $filename_frontimage = time() . '_' .$actual_filename_frontimage;

    $file_frontimage->storeAs('images', $filename_frontimage, 'public');
}
```

Comment: You can make symbolic directory one to another. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may do that specifying an **absolute** path. To do that you may create a custom disk in the config file named `config/filesystems.php`. **The key point is that you are creating that disk in the sub-domain end**. Open that config file up and modify it as your need as the below:

```
<?php

'disks' => [

    'local' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app'),
    ],
    
    // Here is your custom disk
    'parent_disk' => [
        'driver' => 'local',

        // This should be a correct absolute path, so change it with yours
        'root'   => '/home/your_username/public_html/storage/app/public',
        'visibility' => 'public',
    ],
     
    // More disks
],
```

Next up, you specify the disk name while uploading images from your sub-domain.

```
<?php

if ($request->hasFile('frontimage')) {
    $file_frontimage = $request->file('frontimage');
    $actual_filename_frontimage = $file_frontimage->getClientOriginalName();
    $filename_frontimage = time() . '_' .$actual_filename_frontimage;
    
    // Notice the 3rd argument that is the disk name
    // you created in sub-domain via `config/filesystems.php` file
    $file_frontimage->storeAs('images', $filename_frontimage, 'parent_disk');
}
```

This may be more portable than using symbolic link.

Comment: Thank Sir.Your code is perfectly working. But if I want to create 3 thumbnail size of the same image, only one thumbnail image is getting saved. Can you help me?

$file_frontimage->storeAs('thumbnailimages', '525x350'.$filename_frontimage, 'parent_disk');
            $thumbnailpath_525x350= public_path('storage/thumbnailimages/'.'525x350'.$filename_frontimage);
            $img_525x350= Image::make($thumbnailpath_525x350)->resize(525,350);
            $img_525x350->save($thumbnailpath_525x350);

Comment: Thumbnail image is getting saved but Error is showing like

"Intervention\Image\Exception\NotReadableException
Image source not readable"

Comment: Well, it's somewhat strange! I tested it and it works. [Here is the code](https://pastebin.com/CS0J2NTJ) I used.